# How did this message get onto my question?

Tags: support, post-notice

On [my question](https://superuser.com/questions/679641/why-do-i-go-through-to-comcast-so-many-times-before-i-reach-a-website/679747?noredirect=1#679747) I noticed a message:

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and
>   context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is
>   right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations
>   may be removed.

It's located right under my question. Out of curiousity, how did it get there, who put it there and why is there no information (maybe a link leading to a FAQ page) there?

Comment: A moderator placed it there

Answer (score 5):

If you check [the post history](https://superuser.com/posts/679641/revisions), you'll see:

> **Notice added** Insufficient explanation by Daniel Beck♦

That's a boilerplate text moderators can add as a so-called post notice. A post notice will be displayed below a question or answer for a specified amount of time.

There are other templates:

> This post does not cite any references or sources. Please help improve this article by adding citations to reliable sources. Unsourced material may be challenged and removed.

And:

> Post is related to a rapidly changing event.

Comment: Wish there were flags for requesting that a mod add these to a post. Would be nice to have seen these on more than a few posts I've encountered.

Comment: If you feel that a post deserves a notice (because it attracts lots of poor answers), then please flag it, use the "other" reason, and a moderator will have a look. As for the "This post does not cite any references or sources.", this is obviously something you can add as a comment yourself—no need to have a moderator tell a user to back up their statements. At least on Super User we mostly use post notices on questions.